# How do i log output of background program in a file

Tags: 14.04

i am running a program on ubuntu linux server at the background using `setsid <program name>` normally, the programs prints its output in the terminal but i want to see the output in a file, like a log file even while the program runs at the background. How can i achieve that?

Comment: `setsid programName > logfile`

Comment: i get this error "setsid: failed to execute bifrost: No such file or directory" the name of the program is "bifrost server"

Comment: I guess this should work: `setsid ./bifrost\ server  > logfile`. (if you are in the directory which contains your program).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect the output of a command to a function but suppress the error and output to console?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225491/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-a-command-to-a-function-but-suppress-the-error-and)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a recent version of *bash* and also want to detach the program to the background you could use this command:

```
setsid programname &>> logfile &
```