# How to redirect the output of a command to a function but suppress the error and output to console?

Tags: bash, error-handling, stdout, timestamp

I need to redirect the output of a command that I am running to a log file with timestamp (hence a function instead of the log file itself) but the error and the output, both should not be showing in the console. The following -

```
command | my_func 2> /dev/null
```

is not working.

Something like

```
command 2> logfile
```

works, but I can't record the timestamp in the second case. What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not even need a function for that!

To redirect errors to `/dev/null` and output to a file with time and date, you could use `sed` like so:

```
command 2> /dev/null | sed -e "s/^/$(date) /" >> logfile
```

`sed -e "s/^/$(date) /"` will append the current date in this format `Thu 09 Apr 2020 07:06:14 AM +03` to the beginning of each line and add a space between the date and the output for readability purposes.

---

**Notice:**

- To redirect both error and output to a file with time and date, use this:

```
command 2>&1 | sed -e "s/^/$(date) /" >> logfile
```

- To use timestamp in seconds since the Unix epoch like this `1586406740`. change `$(date)` to `$(date +%s)`

Best of luck

Comment: Note that here the timestamp will be the time the command is invoked, not the time the output is generated, which could be a huge difference for long-running processes.

Comment: This almost worked for me, except that it overwrites the contents of the log file every time I run the script. The time difference you mentioned is not significant in my use case.

Comment: @user4002112 ` > logfile` will overwrite the log file, but `>> logfile` will append to the log file. Please make sure to use `>>` and not `>`

Comment: no I am using >>

Comment: @user4002112 Then it shouldn't and can't overwrite ( clear the file and delete existing lines ) unless there is something else in your script/function accessing the same file. If you want me to look at it, please add your code and how you use the command in it to your question.

Comment: @Raffa, thanks, it worked for me, I was overwriting in an earlier command.

Comment: @user4002112 Well done and you are most welcome.

Comment: @user4002112 If one of the answers solved your issue, please take a moment to [accept it](//$$SITEURL/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on [the checkmark on the left](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/203101). That will mark the question as answered and is the way that thanks are conveyed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 7):

It seems you want:

```
command 2> /dev/null | my_func
```

which redirects the stderr of `command` to `/dev/null`, but pipes stdout to `my_func`. (Side note: You might want to check out [the `ts` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/ts.1.html)).

Comment: Assuming your `my_func` is doing the task of writing to the file, `command 2>&1 | my_func` or (bash-specific) `command |& my_func`, which redirects stderr to stdout, and stdout is already piped to my_func.

Comment: If your `my_func` isn't writing to the file, then `command 2>&1 | my_func > some/file`

Answer (score 2):

If a timestamp is all that is needed see `ts` from the `moreutils` package.

```
command | ts

$ sudo apt install moreutils
```

Comment: something like this `command 2>&1 | ts >> command.log`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use GNU awk:

```
myprogram | gawk '{print strftime(), $0}' >> logfile
```

If you also want to log standard error (assumes bash shell):

```
myprogram |& gawk '{print strftime(), $0}' >> logfile
```